# Android WebView on Chromebook cannot scroll

Tags: android, webview, scroll, chromebook

I have a WebView based Android app, which works well on Android devices. However when the same app is run on a Chromebook, with mouse only, no touch screen available, the mouse cursor over the entire web view is the text selection cursor (the I beam), and selects text, but you can't scroll the page at all. Well, if you start selection and drag it above or below screen, it does scroll, but normal scrolling is impossible.

Is there some solution to this problem on Chromebooks? I tested other apps, that show long text content in regular TextView derived controls, and they show a small hand cursor, normal scrolling is available on Chromebook. Not so in WebView control. I tested even a very basic WebView, without any Javascript enabled, showing a simple text only web page, same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently on a Chromebook with a touchpad, no touch screen, you are supposed to scroll content with two fingers... How a typical user would know about this, I have no idea. I had to do extensive search of developer resources to find out...